# Как проверить содержит ли List<T> структуру с определенными полями?

Tags: c#

Есть структура, обьект и лист:

```
Palyer{
   int data;
   int a;
   Col b;
};

List<Player> A;
Player B;
```

Нужно проверить:

```
(A[i].a == B.a && A[i].a == B.b) == true?
```

Можно ли сделать эту проверку типа так: A.Contains(B)?
Я пробовал, но похоже, что A.Contains(B) проверяет:

```
(A[i].a == B.a && A[i].a == B.b && A[i].data==B.data) == true
```

Comment: Перегрузите методы [GetHashCode](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetype.gethashcode) и [Equals](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetype.equals). Студия может помочь в их генерации: [Generate Equals and GetHashCode method overrides in Visual Studio](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/generate-equals-gethashcode-methods)

Comment: Спасибо!
Нужно же cгенерировать  и оставить только Equals()?

Comment: А лучше написать отдельный класс, реализующий `IEqualityComparer<Player>` и использовать Linq-метод Contains

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Складывается ощущение, что тут засели сплошные функциональщики, которые используют неэффективный с точки зрения оптимизации LINQ. Используйте старый как мир `Array.Find` / `List.Find`:

```cs
int FindIndex(List<Player> players, Player player)
{
    // checks

    return players.FindIndex(p => p.a == player.a && p.b == player.b);
}
```

---

Я не понимаю только 1-го: зачем вам `struct Player`?! Сделайте так:

```cs
public sealed class Entity
{
    public Vector2 Position { get; set; }
    public Vector2 Velocity { get; set; }
    public EntityBehavior Behavior { get; set; }
    public object Tag { get; set; }
    // ...

    public Entity(/*...*/) { /*...*/ }
}
```

---

*Всегда* переопределяйте `Equals` в структуре, т. к. стандартная реализация у структур сравнивает все поля через рефлексию. Рефлексию! Это оч. медленно (читайте Рихтера (CLR via C#)).

Comment: struct не создает мусора для GC как class, потому выбрал struct.

Comment: @Alerr Вы можете использовать пул объектов

Comment: Да нет, не стоит. Если бы я знал максимальное число элементов, тогда еще может быть. А так этот пул придется увеличивать / уменьшать. Больше мороки.

"тандартная реализация у структур сравнивает все поля через рефлексию" - спасибо, прямо жизнь спасаете :)

Comment: `int FindIndex(List<Player> players, Player player)`

Answer (score 1):

Можно так, "в лоб" с помощью Linq

```csharp
if (A.Any(x => x.a == B.a && x.b == B.b && x.data == B.data))
{
    // содержит как минимум один такой элемент, но может и больше
}
else
{
    // не содержит
}
```

Comment: Можно использовать `List.Find`

Comment: @return да, но в этом случае структура [должна реализовать](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.find?view=netframework-4.8) интерфейс `IEquatable<T>`

Comment: нет! в том и прикол `List.Find`, что его сигнатура выглядит так: `Find(Predicate<T> match)` В этот `match` мы и вставляем наш `Predicate`. Или вы никогда его не использовали, что не можете отличить `Contains` от `Exists`/`Find`?

Comment: @return никогда не использовал, `.Any` меня полностью устраивает. Но спасибо, покопаюсь для общего развития.